# Lightning: Is there a way to index custom fields to show in the instant global search results?

Tags: lightning, custom-object, global-search

We are using a lot of custom objects in multi-lingual social work context.  So the *name* for the record is the English spelling, but we also want to be able to quick global search based on the local, non-English spelling, as well as a code number for each child.

Is this possible to add in new fields to be indexed?

Comment: I think you would need to open a support case for this - please review https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006007&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Another option would be to install an appexchange package that can do this for you, however, not through the global search, but a component included in the package (which can be included in either lightning or visualforce)

Comment: @glls from that linked doc though, I’m not clear if this would enable the field I’ve set as an external ID to be searchable from the Lightning Global Search, with instant results?  They are available when hitting enter and being taken to the search results page, but I’m specifically after the instant/quick search area

Comment: Sorry, my vernacular was all over the place there.  I'm specifically referring to "Instant Results as You Type" as referenced here:  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_desktop_mobile_comp.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: I dont believe so - it states "recently used records" and  "matching records that you haven't accessed recently"

Comment: what is it exactly that you are trying to achieve? (what is your use case)

Comment: Ya, it’s the “matching records” that is a bit unspecific.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62493/discussion-between-glls-and-peripatew).

Answer (score 0):

The global header in lightning cannot be configured at the moment, as per classic, there is a list of configurable options with the search which can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_search_settings.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

For a customized search, you are better of with a custom lightning app and/or installing an existing AppExchange package that can offer you the specified customizations.